# Find $y$ given that $(1+x_1y)(1+x_2y)\cdots(1+x_ny)=a$

Tags: polynomials

Express $y$ in terms of $x_i$ and $a$, given that $1\geq x_i\geq0$,
$a\geq1$, and

\begin{align}
(1+x_1y)(1+x_2y)\cdots(1+x_ny)&=a,\\
x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n&=1.\\
\end{align}

For $n=2,3$ I can find using quadratic and cubic formulas. But how to do it for general case?

Comment: I don't think that you can find $y$ explicitly if $n>4$ (there is no formula for solving polynomial equations of degree $n>5$). Instead, you can make some approximations. For example, you can prove that $y\geq\ln a$ (if $y>0$) by noting that $e^{x_iy}\geq 1+x_iy$.

Comment: @richrow There are formulas. Just not with radicals.